# Como definir um nó filho no Firebase por IONIC 3

Tags: ionic3

Olá, Estou trabalhando em um projeto com o Firebase Realtime Database e o Ionic 3, mas tenho um problema com o nó filho.

por exemplo:
Meu filho é "LkuCxf041hHfRkn3tiq", como definir esse filho para "teste"?

Meu código é:

```
sendMessageModule(){
    this.db.database.ref('/tasks').child(this.uid).push({
      taskM: 'onM'
    })
```

Eu tentei desse jeito também, mas não obtive sucesso:

```
sendMessageModule(){
    this.db.database.ref('/tasks').push({
      taskM: 'onM'
    })
```

Obrigado a todos!